# DocuSign - CreateAndSendEnvelope Routing 1,2,3

Tags: c#, soap, routes, docusignapi

Using ![CreateAndSendEnvelope][1] and having trouble with the routing order.  I would like to include three signers in sequential order.  Signer 1 = agent, Signer 2 = Tenant, Signer 3 = Owner.  Return copy to Agent.

Right now it is sending the document to all recipients at the same time.

Using C# in Soap. - I am open to all feedback:)

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provided the code or XML you're using.  You mention "routing order" so I'd think you're using the `<RoutingOrder>` field but I'll provide what works for me.  It's based on the value you place in `<RoutingOrder>`, not the order you list Recipients in.

```
<ns:Recipients>
  <ns:Recipient>
    <ns:ID>1</ns:ID>
    <ns:UserName>Signer One</ns:UserName>
    <ns:Email>signerone@notreal.com</ns:Email>
    <ns:Type>Signer</ns:Type>
    <ns:RoutingOrder>1</ns:RoutingOrder>
  </ns:Recipient>
  <ns:Recipient>
    <ns:ID>2</ns:ID>
    <ns:UserName>Signer Two</ns:UserName>
    <ns:Email>signertwo@notreal.com</ns:Email>
    <ns:Type>Signer</ns:Type>
    <ns:RoutingOrder>2</ns:RoutingOrder>
  </ns:Recipient>
  <ns:Recipient>
    <ns:ID>3</ns:ID>
    <ns:UserName>Signer Three</ns:UserName>
    <ns:Email>signerthree@notreal.com</ns:Email>
    <ns:Type>Signer</ns:Type>
    <ns:RoutingOrder>3</ns:RoutingOrder>
  </ns:Recipient>
</ns:Recipients>
```

Comment: Reinkesm - Thank you for your help.  I will try to dig up some code, but I really appreciate your help.